# Is it still possible to forward messages from Facebook to another account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Can I forward a message conversation from Facebook to my Gmail account? I no longer see the forwarding option under actions.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, forwarding messages from Facebook to email is not possible. But you can [download a copy of your Facebook data](https://www.facebook.com/help/302796099745838).

> To download a copy of your Facebook data:
>
> 1. Click 'v' *symbol* at the top right of any Facebook page and select **Settings**.
> 2. Click **Download a copy of your Facebook data** below your General Account Settings.
> 3. Click **Start My Archive**.